# CSS position sticky behavior in QooxDoo

Tags: qooxdoo

In CSS I can make an element sticky (not moving when scrolled), using 'position: sticky'.
I would like to get this behavior in Qooxdoo.

See [Playground](https://qooxdoo.org/qxl.playground/#%7B%22code%22%3A%22var%2520container%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.container.Composite(%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520new%2520qx.ui.layout.Grid()%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520).set(%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520padding%253A%252020%252C%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D)%253B%250A%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520this.getRoot().add(container%252C%2520%257B%2520edge%253A%25200%2520%257D)%253B%250A%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520var%2520sticky%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.basic.Label(%2522sticky%2522).set(%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520padding%253A%252030%252C%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520backgroundColor%253A%2520%27yellow%27%252C%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520width%253A%252050%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D)%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520sticky.getContentElement().setStyle(%257Bposition%253A%2520%27sticky%27%257D)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520var%2520label2%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.basic.Label(%2522Label%25202%2520%2522).set(%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520padding%253A%252030%252C%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520backgroundColor%253A%2520%27green%27%252C%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520width%253A%2520500%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D)%253B%250A%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520container.add(sticky%252C%2520%257B%2520row%253A%25200%252C%2520column%253A%25200%2520%257D)%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520container.add(label2%252C%2520%257B%2520row%253A%25201%252C%2520column%253A%25200%2520%257D)%253B%250A%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%250A%22%2C%20%22mode%22%3A%22ria%22%7D) for code example.
The element that is supposed to be sticky is moving when scrolled horizontally.
How can I make it sticky in Qooxdoo?

The question is not about CSS, but about Qooxdoo.

My code:

```
var container = new qx.ui.container.Composite(
    new qx.ui.layout.Grid()
  ).set({
    padding: 20,
  });

  this.getRoot().add(container, { edge: 0 });

  var sticky = new qx.ui.basic.Label("sticky").set({
    padding: 30,
    backgroundColor: 'yellow',
    
  });
  
  sticky.getContentElement().setStyle({position: 'sticky'});
  
  var label2 = new qx.ui.basic.Label("Label 2 ").set({
    padding: 30,
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    width: 500
  });

  container.add(sticky, { row: 0, column: 0 });
  container.add(label2, { row: 1, column: 0 });
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution was the use of 'allowShrinkX' property.